# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when editing DataGridView bound to BindingList

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

I have a DataGridView which is bound to a BindingList. The DGV has three columns, two of them containing DateTime values and one containing a string. Therefore the first two columns are custom columns with a DateTimePicker as editing control (I implemented this based on an example from Microsoft).
I've set AllowUserToAddRows to false because I want the user to press a button in order to add a new row. When the button is pressed, I add a new entry to my BindingList. So far this works fine, a new row is added to the DGV as soon as I press the button.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.Breaks.Add(new TimePeriod());

        /*foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvBreaks.Rows)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("row " + row.Index);
        }*/
    }
```

But when I click in a cell to edit the content, I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException in the InitializeEditingControl() method because the RowIndex of that cell is -1. It doesn't matter which cell I click (in case I added several new rows), I always get this exception.

```
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // set the value of the editing control to the current cell value
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

        DataGridViewTimeEditingControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewTimeEditingControl;

        // exception occurrs here when accessing Value
        if ((Value == null) || (Value == DBNull.Value))
        {
            ctl.Value = (DateTime)DefaultNewRowValue;
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.Value = (DateTime)Value;
        }
    }
```

I found out that the exception does not occur if I loop through all rows in the DGV directly after adding the row to the BindingList (see commented foreach loop above). But this code is just senseless (I only used it to print out all rows of the DGV after adding a new one).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

I have a stripped example project which can reproduce the problem. You can download it from [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqFOP4u7OkDahF4QDxjje88yR7Kg).

Comment: Almost certainly no one is going to fetch your linked project. Not to mention that external links go stale ridiculously fast, making the question less useful over time. You are probably going to be asked to provide relevant details from that project here.

Comment: How can I provide this project otherwise if not per such link? Can I attach it somehow to this post?

Comment: I don't know what your "project" is, but I can't imagine anyone is going to download and open it. If the question needs some detail from the project, it should be reproduced here in the body of the question. (Sometimes an interested person may ask for a link like this in a chat, which is fine. My point is that external links don't work in SO questions.)

Comment: My "project" is just a stripped down / minimal version of my program that contains just those parts which are needed to reproduce the problem. But it is still too much code to paste it all here into the post.

Comment: If there is anything relevant and useful in the project, it ought to be included here.